# How to work and publish npm repo dependent on other local repo

Tags: git, npm

I haven't made npm repo before and this could be my first repo.

I am not sure, how people typically publish npm repo.

So I have a main **Project A** where I have built multiple component which I think could be useful to others as well.

On a top level, **Component A** is made by multiple components (**Component B**, **Component C**).

I will make Component B and Component C as npm repo as well

In my **Project A**, I can reference `Component A` by local path i.e `'./../opensource-repos/componentA` which is fine.

Now, In component A should I reference `component B` and`component c` as well with local paths? I am afraid that if I reference them by local paths, I might accidentally push `Component A` at some point with local path to `npm`.

How do people generally work in such scenario?